# Copying data from Userform CheckBox and Textbox to columns

Tags: excel, vba, copy, userform

I am trying to create a tool with a userform where the user types a Model in a textbox and selects all the countries where this Model comes from in 10 possible checkboxes.

This information is transferred to "Country" Worksheet through command button.

My code places textbox value in column A and country name from checkbox label in column B.
The problem is that I have more than one country for the same model so I'm getting blank cells without matching Model.
E.g. "Type A" belongs to USA, Brazil, Sweden and Mexico, so I should have "Type A" copied four times along country names instead of just one.

```vb
Private sub Transfer()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aCol As Range
    Dim BS As Worksheet
    
    Set aCol = Worksheets("Country").Range("A:A")
    Set BS = Worksheets("Country")
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        With Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i)
            If .Value Then
                aCol.Cells(82, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Caption
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
    Dim b As Integer
    b = 1
        
    Do Until BS.Range("A" & b).Value = ""

    b = b + 1

end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you shared and without major changes, I would suggest you to think about writing the info contained in the textbox within the loop of the checkboxes and right after the if. This way you will be adding the textbox text no matter what avoiding the blanks

```
If .Value Then
    aCol.Cells(82, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox1").Text
    aCol.Cells(82, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Caption
End If
```

Let me know if that works, below the full code I used to replicate your issue:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Transfer
End Sub


Private Sub Transfer()
Dim i As Long
Dim aCol As Range
Dim BS As Worksheet

Set aCol = Worksheets("Country").Range("A:A")
Set BS = Worksheets("Country")

    For i = 1 To 3
        With Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i)
            If .Value Then
                aCol.Cells(82, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox1").Text
                aCol.Cells(82, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Caption
                
            End If
        End With
        Next i
End Sub
```

[How the form I did looks in VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU3FH.png)

[How the results look like in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3HSO.png)

Comment: Thank you Iñigo S, that loop works BEAUTIFULLY! You are a genius.